# Render not showing active changes in movement of object I've tried almost everything

Tags: rendering, rigging, pose-mode, object-mode

Basically I finished everything in the scene but the final posing and rigs won't show up in the render. The specific problem is the hand, it keeps going behind the phone after I move it and adjust is in front. I changed the mode l, deleted the layer even played with the post processing and specular, I am using a set pose downloaded for my Sim but that shouldn't be the problem right? I should still be able to edit the posing and have it stay in place for the final render.

[image: this is before me moving the nodes on the hand to place it in front of the phone]

[image: This is during me moving and adjusting the nodes of the hand and fingers]
And this is the render image as you can see it's showing the fingers before the positioning ere][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6hY0.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6hY0.jpg)
I'm using a downloaded pose from the internet and wanted to adjust the hand to make it fit but it continues to go and only show the previous pose I did model the hair bc it was also clipping with the hand and phone but how do I get the render to be the same as the camera?? ere][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWrPa.png)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWrPa.png)
[image: Here are some of my settings]
[![more of my settings][6]][6]
[image: others of my settings]

Comment: We need further information to answer, including a screenshot of the problem and possibly a blend file. The difference between viewport and render often comes from modifier stack, that's what I would check first.

Comment: It's definitely has something to do with the pose bc when I click on the rig vs the pose it switches to something else and then I go back and the pose is reset back to the hand being behind and clipped

Comment: But I will check that

Comment: Also it's blender 2.8 btw

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert loc/rot/size keyframes for the bones before rendering or else they will revert to the last (keyframed) pose

It's a bit of an annoyance/bug